Using AG-grid community addition in offline mode
I am adding Ag-grid community addition (plain JavaScript version) into my django/python app.
I was able to make inline editing and other cool free features work by inserting into my base.html.
<script> src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ag-grid-community/dist/ag-grid-community.min.js"></script>

Now, I was asked to copy that js into the repository so that it will work when/if we don't have internet. I copied the content of
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ag-grid-community/dist/ag-grid-community.min.js

into my static/js folder  and called it ad-grid-community.min.js, so now my base.html file has this link instead:
<script src="{% static 'js/ag-grid-community.min.js' %}"></script>

However, now a lot of inline-editing features in my ag-grid table stopped working. I am guessing i need to install additional modules, but how do i do that?
